# Let $A,B,X$ be subgroups of $G$ and $A \subset X \subset AB$. Prove that $A(B \cap X)=X$

Tags: group-theory

Let $A,B,X$ be subgroups of $G$ and $A \subset  X \subset AB$. Prove that $A(B \cap X)=X$

I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Are you sure that is $\;B\cup X\;$ and **not** $\;\color{red}{B\cap X}\;$ ?

Comment: Or is it $A(B \cup X) = AB?$

Comment: i have edited it

Answer (score 1):

Hint (almost proof):

According to [Dedekind's Unimodular Law](http://planetmath.org/modularlaw) (which you should prove if you haven't studied yet)

$$A(B\cap X)=A(X\cap B)=X\cap AB=X$$

Be sure you can justify/prove each step above.

Comment: why is it necessary to change the order from B $\cap$ X to X $\cap$ B?

Comment: It is not, @ZZS14 : I just did it to take the order you wrote and *then* to use the order in which DUL usually appears.

Comment: oh okay, we have never studied this dedekind's unimodular law, i don't really understand the link either.

Comment: Well, then just prove the middle (the second) equality, @ZZS14. It's easy and it is the modular law.

Comment: would it be A(X $\cap$ B) = AX $\cap$ AB = X $\cap$ AB since A,X are subgroups?

Comment: @ZZS14, I've changed the link to an easier one. In this new one they talk about modules but it is the same for groups in general, and the $\;+\;$ sign there is just the multiplication operation in the group, so you can change it freely.

Comment: No @ZZS14, the unimodular law says it is as it is written, and it is easily provable. Try it.

Comment: is it some form of dimW+dimU=dim(U+W)+dim(U∩W)? i have studied this in algebra. 
I really don't understand

Comment: @ZZS14, just prove the double implication: $\;t\in A(X\cap B)\implies t\in X\cap AB\;$ , and the other way around.